# Upgrade receiver trigger multiple times

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, android-resources, android-broadcast

I am currently facing a problem in my application where application upgrade receiver is called multiple times. Below is the manifest code:

```
<receiver android:name=".receiver.UpgradeReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REPLACED" />
                <data android:scheme="package" android:path="com.example" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

***UpgradeReceiver.java***

```
public Context context;
private static final String TAG = "UpgradeReceiver";

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    this.context = context;
    if (null == intent) {
        return;
    }

    String action = intent.getAction();
    Log.i(TAG, "Upgrade_Intent_Package[" + intent.getPackage() + "]");
    Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
    StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
    if (bundle != null) {
        Set<String> keys = bundle.keySet();
        Iterator<String> it = keys.iterator();
        while (it.hasNext()) {
            String key = it.next();
            str.append(key);
            str.append(":");
            str.append(bundle.get(key));
        }
    }
    Log.i(TAG, str.toString());
    if (Constants.UPGRADE_COMPLETED.equalsIgnoreCase(action)) {

    }
}
```

}

I am trying to filter the upgrade broadcast intents with the application package so that only when my application is upgraded the receiver gets executed.

I tried setting the application package name under the path tag in the manifest but it was of no help. In addition, I also tried to extract the package name from the intent using **intent.getPackage()** but it returns null. However, Android states that:

> Broadcast Action: A new version of an application package has been
>   installed, replacing an existing version that was previously
>   installed. The data contains the name of the package.

I am unable to figure out why my application package name is null. Any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`intent.getPackage()` returns the package/application this intent was specifically adressed to but it was sent to any interested receiver therefore there isn't such package.

Use `intent.getData()` which returns the updated package as an `Uri`